# Way to prevent snippet of template from being cached?

Tags: cache

I have some PHP logic in a template that randomly loads some content. Logged in, this works great. Logged out, caching prevents different content from being loaded each refresh.

Is there a good way around this, aside from excluding the particular page from cache (in my case, Varnish)? All clever solutions welcome.

Comment: Well the whole point of the cache is to prevent the page being needlessly regenerated each refresh. If the content is updated frequently enough that this is  a problem then you should just not cache that page. The alternative would be to load the content in dynamically after the page has loaded with AJAX.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense @JacobPeattie -- I ended up loading all of the content with inline styles hiding them all, then used JS to display one at random.